# Would repartitioning in spark change number of spark partitions whilst reading data from cassandra source?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am reading a table from cassandra table in spark. I have big partition in cassandra and when partition size of cassandra exceeds 64 MB , in that case cassandra partition is going to be equal to spark partition. Due to large partition I am getting memory issues in spark.

My question is if I do repartition at the beginning after reading data from cassandra, would number of spark partitions change ? and would it not lead to spark memory issues ?

My assumption is at very first place spark would read data from cassandra and hence at this stage cassandra large partition won't split due to repartition . Repartition will work on underlying data loaded from cassandra.

I am just wondering for answer if repartition could change data distribution when reading data from spark , rather than doing partitioning again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you repartition your data using some arbitrary key then yes, it will be redistributed among the Spark partitions.

Technically, Cassandra partitions do not get split into Spark partitions when you retrieve the data but once you're done reading, you can repartition on a different key to break up the rows of a large Cassandra partition.

For the record, it doesn't avoid the memory issues of reading large Cassandra partitions in the first place because ​the default input split size of 64MB is just a notional target that Spark uses to calculate how many Spark partitions are required based on the estimated Cassandra table size and C* partition sizes. But since the calculation is based on estimates, the Spark partitions don't actually end up being 64MB in size.

If you are interested, I've explained in detail how Spark partitions are calculated in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/11500/.

To illustrate with an example, let's say that based on the estimated table size and estimated number of C* partitions, each Spark partition is mapped to 200 token ranges in Cassandra.

For the first Spark partition, the token range might only contain 2 Cassandra partitions of size 3MB and 15MB so the actual size of the data in Sthe park partition is just 18MB.

But in the next Spark partition, the token range contains 28 Cassandra partitions that are mostly 1 to 4MB but there is one partition that is 56MB. The total size of this Spark partition ends up being a lot more than 64MB.

In these 2 cases, one Spark partition was just 18MB in size while the other is bigger than the 64MB target size. I've explained this issue in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/11565/. Cheers!